# Calculate how many radians a train has turned

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, rotations

> A toy train moves around a circular track of radius $0.80 \text{ m}$. 
>   How many radians has the train turned through in moving $2.2 \text{ m}$ along the track?"

I'm not sure how to work out how many radians the train has turned is there a specific equation for this ?

Comment: Note that the tag (mathematical-physics) is for a specific field of physics.  You want to use the (physics) tag along with any other relevant tags for your questions.

Comment: Okay thanks I will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given radius $0.80$ metres and the train has turned $2.2m$.

This situation is similar to that of:

Length of arc= $2.2m$ and Radius= $0.80m$.

The angle in radian, length of arc and radius are related as (I think it is known to you):

$\theta=$length of arc/radius.

So angle in radians=$\theta$=$2.2/0.8$=$11/4 radians$

Comment: Thank you for showing your detailed working. It has helped me to understand this much better (: